# Does running two scripts in parallel on a dual-core CPU decrease the speed as compared to running them serially?

Tags: python, performance

I was wondering whether running two scripts on a dual-core CPU (in parallel at the same time) decreases the speed of the codes as compared to running them serially (running at different times or on two different CPUs). What factors should be considered into account while trying to answer this question?

Comment: I didn't understand what you consider to be the difference between "running two scripts on a dual-core CPU" and "running them separately". In the first case, aren't you also running them separately? In the second case, do you consider the same or a different CPU?

Comment: You mean running them in parallel or serially? If you run them in parallel, it will usually get done faster. But, what else is going on in the machine? Other programs may be competing for those two cores. And what is the program doing? If they both are using the same resource, like a hard drive, there may be little benefit to parallelization. And memory. If these things are memory hogs, you may make things worse with both of them running.

Comment: By running both at the same time I meant running them in parallel. By running them separately, I meant running them in serial (or running them at different times or on different CPUs). Now revised the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; assuming the processes can run independently (neither one is waiting on the other one to move forward), they will run faster in parallel than in serial on a multicore system. For example, here's a little script called `busy.py`:

```
for i in range(400000000):
    pass
```

Running this once, on its own:

```
$ time python busy.py

real    0m6.875s
user    0m6.871s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Running it twice, in serial:

```
$ time (python busy.py; python busy.py)

real    0m14.702s
user    0m14.701s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Running it twice, in parallel (on a multicore system - relying on the OS to assign different cores):

```
$ time (python busy.py & python busy.py)

real    0m7.849s
user    0m7.843s
sys     0m0.004s
```

If we run `python busy.py & python busy.py` or a single-core system, or simulate it with [taskset](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html), we get results that looks more like the serial case than the parallel case:

```
$ time (taskset 1 python busy.py & taskset 1 python busy.py)

real    0m13.057s
user    0m13.035s
sys     0m0.013s
```

There is some variance in these numbers because, as @tdelaney mentioned, there are other applications competing for my cores and context-switches are occurring. (You can see how many context-switches occurred with `/usr/bin/time -v`.)

Nonetheless, they get the idea across: running twice in serial necessarily takes twice as long as running once, as does running twice in "parallel" (context-switching) on a single core. Running twice in parallel on two separate cores takes only about as long as running once, because the two processes really can run at the same time. (Assuming they are not waiting on each other, competing for the same resource, etc.)

This is why the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module is useful for parallelizable tasks in Python. ([threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) can also be useful, if the tasks are IO-bound rather than the CPU-bound.)

Answer (score 0):

### How Dual Cores Works When Running Scripts

**running two separate scripts**

if you run one script then another script on a dual core CPU, then
weather or not your scripts will run on each of the cores is dependent on
your Operating System.

**running two separate threads**
on a dual core CPU then your threads will actually be faster than on a single core.